# ASP:Table adding rows programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add rows programmatically to a server side table in asp.net. I have a button, and within the click event handler I have:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

row.Cells.Add(cell);
myServersideTable.Rows.AddAt(myServersideTable.Rows.Count - 1, row);
```

All good, the code works the first time the button is clicked and a new row is added.

However, all subsequent button clicks don't add a new row. No error is thrown.

Why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a row dynamically, so when you postback you will have to again recreate the controls.

In this case you are using a Table and the row is added on first button click, so when you click again you will have to recreate the previous row again and one more for the current click

Comment: ah! I get it. Thanks. Not what I was hoping, going to have to think of a different way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because of the stateless nature of `Http` protocol. For more information please read ASP.NET page life cycle from the MSDN.

Answer (score -2):

```
dim row as new TableRow()
 
dim cell as new TableCell()

col.text = "abcd"

row.Controls.Add(cell)'

myServersideTable.rows.add(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Comment: In addition to @AztecCodes’ points, you provided VB.NET code on a question tagged with C#, so this isn’t going to address the original question.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Where did I provide VB.NET Code?

Comment: @AztecCodes: You didn’t. Please reread my comment. I was reaffirming what you said n your comment. Then I was adding that the author’s answer was in the wrong language for the post.